# Jmeter >> ChromeWebDriver >> Having issue while running in Bamboo, Maven it works

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins, bamboo, jmeter-5.0

working on Jmeter , which has chrome webdriver on it.
when i build from maven locally , it works fine,
but when i try running in Bamboo, driver is not executing .

getting this error in Bamboo

2024-03-11 01:43:54,388 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: _SanityScript 1-1
2024-03-11 01:43:54,436 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Actual executable Unable to find executable for: /opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MOZ-MUPS-LOAD/MUPFormsSanityScript/target/af52d122-4105-45d7-b873-17f713a00fc6/jmeter/bin/C:\Stash\mup.test\MUPFormsSanityScript\src\test\resources\Drivers\chromedriver.exe

do we need to update any config specifically for chrome driver?

Comment: Have a very good look at the path in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking into `/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/` your Bamboo agent is deployed on Linux system hence you need the Chromedriver for `linux64`. It can be downloaded from [Chrome for Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) dashboard
2. The `chromedriver` will not be present on the Bamboo agent executor machine, most probably you will need to download it either in the previous step or directly in your test, i.e. somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
3. You might also need to make this `chromedriver` binary executable by running [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command, it can be done using either a separate step in your job configuration or via i.e. [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) or [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in the aforementioned setUp Thread Group

Comment: Thanks for your response. changed few things to make it working . 1) changed from linux to windows machine, 2) chromedriver and csv which i have used , directory is not getting identified by Bamboo , so moved to the project base directory to make it working ,